# THREE.MeshPhongMaterial.displacementMap mapping negative values

Tags: three.js

I'm using a ShaderMaterial to generate noise to a render texture.

Then I'm using the resulting texture as a displacementMap on a plane using phong shading material.

What happens is that the displacement map will go from [0-displacementScale].
Meaning that my noise texture will be interpreted per pixel as: 0x000000 pixels means 0 vertex offset, and 0xffffff pixels means the `displacementScale` value...

I thought the displacementBias would allow me to map the range, but it kind of just offsets the "average".

I would like to know how could I map the range from the displacementMap so 0x000000 could mean e.g: -100 and the 0xffffff could mean 100...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source file `displacementmap_vertex.glsl`, you will find the displacement formula:

```
transformed += normal * ( texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).x * displacementScale + displacementBias );
```

So in your case, set `displacementBias` = -100 and `displacementScale` = 200.

three.js r.73